# In a circle of radius $1$ we draw a chord "randomly". Determine the distribution of its length if the rope is determined by $2$ points on the circle.

Tags: probability

In a circle of radius $1$ we draw a chord "randomly". Determine the distribution of its length if the chord is determined by $2$ points on the circle.

I have to determine the distribution of its length $P$ {$L\leq x$} but I do not know how to solve the problem, I am given the solution by my textbook but I do not comprehend it.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I will post the answer given by my textbook.

Let $L$ be the length of the chord. The given circumference can be rotated so the first randomly chosen point, $A$, can be fixed to be on $(1,0)$.  This way we only have to pick randomly the position of the second point $B$. If $B$ is determined by its angular coordinate $\beta$, the probability space is identified with $((-\pi,\pi], \mathbb{B}_{(-\pi,\pi]},{\lambda}/{2\pi}$).

We draw from $A$ the $2$ chords of length $x$, with $0\leq x \leq 2$, its extremes delimit on the circumference the event {$L\leq x$} and its complement. The angle that encompasses $\{L\leq x\}$ measures $4\arcsin(x/2)$, so the probability function of $L$ is:

$$F_{L}(x)=P\{L\leq x\}=\cfrac{x}{2}\arcsin(\frac{x}{2})$$ for $0\leq x \leq 2$.

The solution also gives the following diagram:

[image]

I do not understand why in the beginbing the author talks about the angular coordinate $\beta$ and where does the expression $4\arcsin(x/2)$ come from. Also, I do not understand what means "the angle that encompasses $\{L \leq x\}$ measures $4\arcsin(x/2)$".

Comment: +1 It is interesting. Could you also post the solution in your book, just take the picture of it?

Comment: I have to translate it, give me half an hour and I will post it

Comment: If the offered solution includes a geometric diagram, please include a picture.  However, for whatever math is involved in the solution, please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: There is the solution given in the textbook.

Comment: $\beta$ is the position of the other end of the rope around the circle in radians, measured from A.  It is uniform on $(-\pi, pi]$.  You should convince yourself that $\alpha=\frac 12 \beta$

Comment: After a thought now I understand that α=1/2β=arcsen(x/2), does anyone have any idea on why the angle is 4arcsen(x/2)?

Comment: you might like to edit your question to say **chord** rather than rope

Answer (score 1):

The angle between the two chords is $\pi-2\alpha=\pi-2\arcsin \frac x2$ because of the right triangle $\alpha$ is in.  The angle it subtends at the center of the circle is twice this, or  $2\pi-4\arcsin \frac x2$.  The length of the circumference outside the angle is then $4\arcsin \frac x2$